# group of footer buttons with css using element ui

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I am trying to replicate this complete using css, I don't get the footer buttons.

[image]

This is what I have achieved so far using el-card of element ui and css

```
     <el-card>
   <div style="cursor: pointer;">
     <p>(15*47*14) Alternador Servo Toy </p>
     <img src="https://demo.facturador.pro/logo/imagen-no-disponible.jpg" class="img-thumbail img-custom">

   </div>
   <div class="card-footer" style="width: 100% ;">
     <el-button-group style="width: 100% ; padding: 0px ;">
       <el-button class="btn-primary-pos" size="mini" type="primary" icon="el-icon-edit"></el-button>
       <el-button class="btn-primary-pos" size="mini" type="primary" icon="el-icon-share"></el-button>
       <el-button class="btn-primary-pos" size="mini" type="primary" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
     </el-button-group>
   </div>


 </el-card>
```

CSS is as follows

```
    .btn-primary-pos {
   background-color: #007bff;
   border-color: #007bff #007bff #007bff;
   color: #FFF;
 }

 .btn-primary-pos:hover,
 .btn-primary-pos.hover {
   background-color: #0069d9;
   border-color: #0069d9;
   color: #FFF;
 }


 .card-footer {
   padding: 0px 0.75rem !important;
 }
```

[image]

https://element.eleme.io/#/es/component/card#con-imagenes

Comment: A complete working example of your code in snippet or code-pen would help us a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easly resolve this with flex box. Your buttons have to grow as they have the size of it's content:

```
<el-button-group class="group" style="width: 100% ; padding: 0px ;">
       <el-button class="btn-primary-pos" size="mini" type="primary" icon="el-icon-edit"></el-button>
       <el-button class="btn-primary-pos" size="mini" type="primary" icon="el-icon-share"></el-button>
       <el-button class="btn-primary-pos" size="mini" type="primary" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
     </el-button-group>
```

CSS :

```
.btn-primary-pos {
   background-color: #007bff;
   border-color: #007bff #007bff #007bff;
   color: #FFF;
   flex-grow: 1;
 }

 .btn-primary-pos:hover,
 .btn-primary-pos.hover {
   background-color: #0069d9;
   border-color: #0069d9;
   color: #FFF;
 }


.group {
  display: flex;
}
```

https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/qBdBGyK

Answer (score 1):

use flexbox. read about flex-grow, display:flex, align-items.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/